# Error about UserControl not supported in WPF in Expression Blend 2

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I've created a test Silverlight 2 app in Visual Studio, just [copying the Tim Heuer video](http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=57010), but when I go to open it in Blend I get this error

> UserControl is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

This is the XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyFirstApp.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" FontSize="60" />
            <Button Content="Click Me" FontSize="60" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Am I missing a reference or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [Expression Blend 2.0 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EB9B5C48-BA2B-4C39-A1C3-135C60BBBE66&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this thread:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/33030347-c99a-4f41-8be7-089c92e4ab2d